# Sub query & joins on different tables having different conditions

Tags: mysql, join, subquery, conditional-statements

I'm trying to get a result from different tables. Need some help to write a query, I'm new to MySQL.

I've 1 table **tbl_opp_details** that contacins `ID's` of different tables:

`moduleId` from `tbl_module`

`relatedId` contains `ID's` related to the perticular module from different tables (tbl_account, tbl_contact, ...).
[image]
In above image,

```
moduleId "1" -> Account (tbl_account)

moduleId "2" -> Contact (tbl_contact)
```

Now I want to display all the information about Accounts, Contacts

```
moduleId "1" -> Account (tbl_account) relatedTo "1" -> pin_1

moduleId "1" -> Account (tbl_account) relatedTo "2" -> epr_2
```

tbl_account

[image]

tbl_contact
[image]

tbl_call_a_log
[image]

Need a query which joins these tables and gives the result.

**Update-1:**
My Query:

```
SELECT 
    callLog.oppCallLogId, 
    callLog.subject, 
    callLog.comments, 
    callLog.moduleId, 
    modules.moduleName, 
    callLog.relatedTo, 
    accounts.account, 
    callLog.createdBy, 
    callLog.createdDtm, 
    callLog.updatedBy, 
    callLog.updatedDtm 
FROM tbl_opp_call_log AS callLog 
INNER JOIN tbl_module AS modules ON modules.moduleId=callLog.moduleId 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT accounts.account FROM tbl_account AS accounts INNER JOIN callLog.relatedTo=accounts.accountId WHERE callLog.moduleId=1)
```

**It gives an error**

> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '.accountId WHERE callLog.moduleId=1) LIMIT 0, 25' at line 16

**Update-2:**

```
SELECT
    callLog.oppCallLogId,
   callLog.subject,
   callLog.comments,
   callLog.moduleId,
   callLog.relatedTo,
   accountTbl.account,
   callLog.createdBy,
   callLog.createdDtm,
   callLog.updatedBy,
   callLog.updatedDtm
FROM tbl_opp_call_log AS callLog
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT accounts.account 
    FROM tbl_account AS accounts 
    INNER JOIN tbl_opp_call_log AS callLog ON callLog.relatedTo=accounts.accountId 
    WHERE callLog.moduleId=1 AND accounts.accountId=callLog.relatedTo) AS accountTbl
ORDER BY callLog.oppCallLogId ASC
```

It repeated output.

Any kind of help is welcome, thanks in advance.

Comment: You should write two queries, one that joins with `tbl_account` when `moduleId = 1`, and another that jois with `tbl_contact` when `module_Id = 2`. Then you can combine them with `UNION` and join with `tbl_call_a_log`.

Comment: @Barmar can you give an example for this?

Comment: Why are you joining with `tbl_opp_call_log` twice? And you have no `ON` clause for the first join, so it does a full cross product.

Comment: Why isn't `tbl_module` in your query?

Comment: What should the result be like when you add in `tbl_contact`?